# scope of expressions and variables in Julia macro in modules

Tags: scope, macros, metaprogramming, julia

For some reason, I had to put `quote`...`end` block in the macro and `ex` is generated programmatically. This code works.

```
macro addsum_out()
  quote
    ex = :(x+y)
    sum(eval(ex))
  end
end

x = [1 1 1]
y = [2 2 2]

z2 = @addsum_out
```

When the macro is put inside a module, it no longer works:

```
module MyModule

export @addsum

macro addsum()
  quote
    ex = :(x+y)
    sum(eval(ex))
  end
end

end

using MyModule
x = [1 1 1]
y = [2 2 2]    
z = @addsum
```

It says:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: x not defined
```

I think I should put `esc` somewhere, to evaluate the expression `ex` in the main scope outside the module. What should I handle this?

Comment: `eval` should not be used in macros. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `eval` operates at module-global scope. Look at `macroexpand( :(@addsum) )` and notice the `MyModule.eval`. Anyway, it is completely unnecessary. You should return `esc(:(x + y) )` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that a macro (inside a module) referencing `x` will look for `x` in that module, e.g. `MyModule.x`

This is part of [macro hygiene](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Hygiene-1).

To prevent macro hygiene from happening, you need to `esc(x)` -- that means it will use whatever x is in-scope at the call-site.

Your complete solution might look like:

```
macro addsum_out()
  quote
    esc(x) + esc(y)
  end
end
```

or more concisely:

```
macro addsum_out()
  :(  esc(x) + esc(y)  )
end
```

Note that this is slightly different from doing `esc( :(x+y) )` which would be a escaping the `+` function also. i.e. the module containing this macro might contain an overload for `+`, and if you want to use this then don't escape the `+`, otherwise do!

There is a little discussion about this subject in a guide I put together:
https://github.com/p-i-/MetaGuideJulia/wiki#example-swap-macro-to-illustrate-esc

Comment: You mean `:(  $(esc(:x)) + $(esc(:y))  )`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `esc(Expr(:call, +, :x, :y))`.